# json.parse allow null or missing

Tags: json, vb.net, string, url, null

MY JSON String

```
{

"name": "username",
"status": "mystatus",
"place": {
"name": "placename",
}
```

My Code

```
  Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader

    Try

        request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://myjsonstring.com/json"), HttpWebRequest)

        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

        Dim rawresp As String
        rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()

        Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)
        if (rawresp != null)
            name.Text = jResults("name").ToString()
            status.Text = jResults("status").ToString()
            placename.Text = jResults("place")("name").ToString()

  End If

    Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)

    Finally
        If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()

    End Try
```

my issue is sometimes my json may look like this

```
{

"name": "username",
"place": {
"name": "placename",
}
```

My JSON Explained

```
"name": "name here",
   "items": {
    "myitem": {
      "icon": "myitem.jpg",
    "myitem2": {
      "icon": "myitem2.jpg",
}
```

My Code I Have Tried

```
myitem.Text = If(jResults2("items")("myitem")("icon") Is Nothing, "", jResults2("items")("myitem")("icon").ToString())
myitem2.Text = If(jResults2("items")("myitem2")("icon") Is Nothing, "", jResults2("items")("myitem2")("icon").ToString())
```

when the value is missing from myitem it stops the JSON and myitem2 never displays.

As this happens my project throws a null value exception, I have severely condensed my json string and code for readability but my question is there a way to handle the error when "status" is missing from the string and continue to parse the rest of the objects?

Or if its possible when this value is missing/null replace it with something else but if this route was chosen I would like to set a different value for each.

Comment: Check if `jResults("status")` is null (`Nothing`) before doing `.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `jResults("status")` and other properties are null (`Nothing`) before doing `.ToString()`.

```
Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)
name.Text = If(jResults("name") Is Nothing, "", jResults("name").ToString())
status.Text = If(jResults("status") Is Nothing, "", jResults("status").ToString())
placename.Text = If(jResults("place") Is Nothing, "", jResults("place")("name").ToString())
```

Comment: ah it seems like that didn't work as its only ever returning the null value even when the status is in the string


Thanks

Comment: So if you changed `status.Text = If(jResults("status") Is Nothing, "", jResults("status").ToString())` back to `status.Text = jResults("status").ToString()`, it works?

Comment: yeah when i changed it back it was fine